# That update query doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, rows-affected

Hello boys and girls :)

I have that query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
INNER JOIN address ON customer.customer_id = address.customer_id
WHERE address.country_id = 176
```

So i want to update `custome.status` to 0
I tried with that query but "0 rows affected":

```
UPDATE customer
INNER JOIN address ON customer.customer_id = address.customer_id
SET customer.status = 0
WHERE address.country_id = 176
```

I have about 200 ppl with address.country_id = 176 !

Any ideas, thank u !

Comment: A sample data and table definitions would be good to reproduce such problems

Comment: Do you have a corresponding record in the `address` table too?

Comment: @Pred Yes, i have first query return me about 200 rows :)

Comment: You sure the data is different then customer.status = 0... if not the query will answer with '0 rows affected'

Comment: Try updating the select query to add `customer.status != 0` so that you know how many records are there that needs to be updated. If it's 0 then update query's output is correct.

Comment: Guys, i''m so sorry to waste your time, the query is right, but status is already 0 ... i really sorry !

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different approach with EXISTS instead of JOIN

```
UPDATE
  customer
SET
  status = 0
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM address A
    WHERE customer.customer_id = A.customer_id AND country_id = 176
  )
```

Can't recall, but is it possible, that MySQL won't report change for those records where status is already equals to 0?